# What should i do when my landlord breaks an agreement, and later invokes the 60 days tenant notice in Ontario

Tags: criminal-law, canada, residential-lease, fraud, landlord

My landlord refused to repair a big mold problem in my former apartment, when i told to the superintendent the mold in the apartment was making me and my kids sick, he yelled i should move out if i didn't like what was paying for, so i did fill the form and gave 45days notice. The overseer in the office didn't dispute the 45days notice because i told her it was because of the mold i was moving out.  20days after i moved out, a had a phone call from a collection agency on behalf of the Landlord saying i am owing them a month rent because i didn't give 60days notice. 
The landlord didn't dispute my notice from the beginning, and there was a verbal agreement with the overseer.
Also the collection agency is threatening to take my wife to the credit bureau, and its my name on the lease, she is just a co-occupant.
Is this legal?

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like it's some sort of fraudulent scam or something. I'm not sure what to do, but it could be wise to check out the Tenants Association's website or something. Chances are, the very fact that there was mold and all in the apartment is likely a breach of Ontario laws.

Answer (score 2):

No that isn't legal.

> big mold problem
>
> the mold in the apartment was making me and my kids sick

Implied warranty of habitability breached. The rent is forfeit until the breach is cured.

If we want to interpret it differently, that it is unusual for this level of mold to make people sick yet it does so for you and your family, we end up with [frustration of purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustration_of_purpose) and the contract still collapses.